# HTTP request with adapter in android

Tags: android

What is the best way to deal with getting more data from the back-end to update a listview?

Is the following the right way to start thinking about it,

Use httpurlconnection, parse the response (i.e JSON) and update an Array adapter that is inflating a listview.

Comment: you can but write Service Manager to call to the Service. As a good programming practice, UI should not directly connect to Services. To communicate between UI and Services create a Business Manager; BM itself will call to desired Service and collect the response. From UI you have to call BM and get result from BM! [NOTE] It is really hectic sometimes, but it'll help you when you'll be working in the company.

Answer (score 0):

HttpURLConnection is the best way doing this,using this you can retrieve the value from the server like JSON response .Parse JSON response accordingly.

When back-end is getting update the values in table,at that time you can update the array adapter using `Handler`

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

   @Override
    public void run() {
   handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
         }
   }, 60 * 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

For Json deserialization I'm using com.google.gson library

// to get data from URL

```
     URL url = new URL(address);
       URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

       connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF8");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        String read;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(read);
        }
        br.close();
       String response = sb.toString();
       connection.getInputStream().close();

       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

       Type listType = new TypeToken<List<YOUR_CLASS>>(){}.getType();

       List<YOUR_CLASS> listOfObjects = gson.fromJson(response,listType);
```

After what you can either update collection of your custom adapter and call notifydatasetChanged() orcreate new instance of adapter with listOfObjects collection.